# Sieve of Eratosthenes in x86 assembly. I cannot figure out what's wrong with the code

Tags: c, assembly, x86, calling-convention, att

I am wrapping up this assignment in my CS class where we are translating the C-code for the Sieve of Eratosthenes-algorithm, to 32-bit assembly code with AT&T syntax. Now, the output is not correct, and I just cannot wrap my head around how to fix it. When I use gdb to debug the assembly code, I notice that the variable **N** is never assigned to **%edx**, which I find very odd. Am I subtracting the wrong number of bytes when assigning the variables to the registers? **%ebp** is located 4 bytes under the return address which is the again 4 bytes below the variables and so on. I believe that my math on this is correct, but that the error lays somewhere else in the code.

Here is some images from GDB, showing the content of the array in C and assembly. Here, **arr_c** has the right elements, while **arr_asm** don't. But it is kinda close (It only matters that the zeroes is at the right indexes):
[image]

and here, you can see the value of **%edx**:
[image]

Can someone explain to me what is happening? Here is the assembly code:

```
.section .text

arr = 8
N   = 12

.global asm_function

asm_function:

    # Prologue, create stack frame
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp

    # Save some registers
    pushl %esi
    pushl %edi
    pushl %edx

    # Registers dedicated for counting
    pushl %eax
    pushl %ebx
    pushl %ecx

    movl $2, %eax                       # %eax = 2 (loop-counter, int i = 2)

    # Move int N to %edx
    movl N(%ebp), %edx

    # Compare i (counter) to N
    condition:
        cmpl %eax, %edx                 # compare i with N
        jb populateArray                # if i is less than N, populate array
        jmp initialize_outer_con        # if not, array is fully populated, start Sieve

    # Initialize array with 1's from arr[0] -> arr[N-1]
    populateArray:
        leal arr(%ebp), %edi            # %edi = &arr
        movl %eax, %esi                  
        movl $1, (%esi, %edi)           # a[i] = 1
        incl %eax                       # i++
        jmp condition

    initialize_outer_con:   
        movl $2, %eax                   # i = 2
        jmp sieve_outer_loop_condition

    # OUTER FOR-LOOP SIEVE
    sieve_outer_loop_condition:
        cmpl %eax, %edx                 # compare i with N
        jb initialize_inner_con         # if i < N, enter initialization of inner loop condition
        jmp exit                        # when every number is checked, assign array address to %eax

    initialize_inner_con:
        movl %eax, %ebx                 # %eax (i) = %ebx (j)
        jmp sieve_inner_loop_condition

    # INNER FOR-LOOP SIEVE
    sieve_inner_loop_condition:
        movl %eax, %ecx

        imul %ebx, %ecx                 # %ecx = i*j

        cmpl %ecx, %edx                 # compare i*j with N
        jb sieve_inner_loop_statements  # if i*j < N, go to statements
        incl %eax
        jmp sieve_outer_loop_condition

    sieve_inner_loop_statements:
        movl %ecx, %esi                 
        movl $0, (%esi, %edi)           # arr[i*j] = 0
        incl %ebx
        jmp sieve_inner_loop_condition

    exit:
        movl arr(%ebp), %eax

    # Epilogue, clean up the stack
    popl %ecx
    popl %ebx
    popl %edx

    popl %edi
    popl %esi
    movl %ebp, %esp
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

...and here is the C-code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>


extern int asm_function();


void c_function(int *arr, int N) 
{
    // Initialize array with 1's from arr[0] -> arr[N-1]
    for(int i = 2; i < N; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = 1;
    }

    // SIEVE
    for(int i = 2; i < N; i++)
    {
        // Set every index that is not a prime number equal to 0 in the array
        for(int j = i; i*j< N; j++)
        {
            arr[i*j] = 0;
        }
    }

    // print the prime numbers
    for(int i = 2; i < N; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] != 0)
            printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int N;
    printf("\n> This program computes every prime number below N\n> using the Sieve of Eratosthenes-algorithm.\n\nPlease enter a number N: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    int arr_c[N];
    int arr_asm[N];

    int *ptr;
    ptr = asm_function();

    // Return from C function
    printf("\n\nC function:\n\n");
    c_function(arr_c, N);

    // Return from Assembly function
    printf("\n\nAssembly function:\n\n");
    for(int i = 2; i < N; i++)
    {
        if(*ptr != 0)
            printf("%d\n", i);
        ptr++;
    }
}
```

**TL;DR**

My assembly code fails somewhere to modify the correct numbers in the input array. The variable N is never set to the right value, and even though that might not be an issue here, I believe that I have some other errors in the code that is beyond my understanding of assembly as I am completely new to it. As I can see, the code seems fine... But it is clearly not (images of the output is attached).

**EDIT 1**
Okay, so I've given the argument N to the assembly function, but I still get the same result. Can someone verify if I am using the right offset when setting the values of N and the array in assembly?

Here's how the C code looks now, while the assembly code is the same:

```
extern int asm_function(int *arr, int N);


void c_function(int *arr, int N) 
{
    // Initialize array with 1's from arr[0] -> arr[N-1]
    for(int i = 2; i < N; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = 1;
    }

    // SIEVE
    for(int i = 2; i < N; i++)
    {
        // Set every index that is not a prime number equal to 0 in the array
        for(int j = i; i*j< N; j++)
        {
            arr[i*j] = 0;
        }
    }

    // print the prime numbers
    for(int i = 2; i < N; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] != 0)
            printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int N = 20;

    int arr_c[N];
    int arr_asm[N];

    int *ptr;
    ptr = asm_function(arr_asm, N);

    // Return from C function
    printf("\n\nC function:\n\n");
    c_function(arr_c, N);

    // Return from Assembly function
    printf("\n\nAssembly function:\n\n");
    for(int i = 2; i < N; i++)
    {
        if(*ptr != 0)
            printf("%d\n", i);
        ptr++;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Okay, so now it seems like the offsets for my constants in asm is right, but the output I am getting is wrong. Here it is:

```
C function:

2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19

Assembly function:

2
4
10
11
13
14
15
```

The output from C and asm should be identical, so something must be wrong with my assembly code. Any suggestions? Can it be that I must increment **%eax** on a other line than on line 77 (in sieve_inner_loop_condition)? I realize now that I could've written the loops a bit simpler without this many jumps

**EDIT 3**
Ok, even more jumps now (fixed some of the counter-registers being reset in some of the loops), but I see no reason why the arr_asm now becomes {2, 6, 11, 18, 19}... When debugging with GDB, it seems like none of the conditional jumps are done...? When im stepping after any **jl < address >**-condition, it seems like the flags are never set, and it goes straight to the jmp statement. Can someone explain this? Doesn't **stepping** in GDB go to the next instruction stored in **EIP**? Some clarification on this would be much appreciated! I feel like I'm lost here as the right flags should be set...

**EDIT 4**
After a lot of debugging and help from @Jester down in the comments, the code now finally works. Thank you, I never realized how powerful this forum could be until now recently - and I will never post any code as images from now on ;)

**Working assembly-implementation of the algorithm "Sieve of Eratosthenes" with AT&T syntax:**

```
.section .text

# Constants - offsets in bytes for the stack base pointer
arr = 8
N   = 12

.global asm_function

asm_function:

    # Prologue, create stack frame
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp

    # Save some registers
    pushl %esi
    pushl %edi
    pushl %edx

    # Registers dedicated for counting
    pushl %eax
    pushl %ebx
    pushl %ecx

    movl $2, %eax                       # %eax = 2 (loop-counter, int i = 2)

    # Place array and N in registers
    movl N(%ebp), %edx                  # %edx = N
    movl arr(%ebp), %edi                # %edi = arr

    # Condition of first loop
    condition:
        cmpl %edx, %eax                 # compare i with N
        jb populateArray                # if i is less than N, populate array
        jmp sieve_init                  # if not, array is fully populated, start Sieve init

    # Initialize array with 1's from arr[0] -> arr[N-1]
    populateArray:
        movl %eax, %esi                  
        movl $1, (%edi, %esi, 4)        # a[i] = 1
        incl %eax                       # i++
        jmp condition                   # Check if condition is still valid, loop

    # Initialize counters
    sieve_init:
        movl $2, %eax                   # %eax (i) = 2
        movl %eax, %ebx                 # %eax (i) = %ebx (j)
        jmp sieve_outer_loop_condition

    # OUTER FOR-LOOP SIEVE
    sieve_outer_loop_condition:
        cmpl %edx, %eax                 # compare i with N
        jb sieve_inner_loop_init        # if i is less than N, enter inner loop initalization
        jmp exit                        # when every number is checked, exit loop and return the array

    sieve_inner_loop_init:
        movl %eax, %ebx                 # %eax (i) = %ebx (j)
        jmp sieve_inner_loop_condition

    # INNER FOR-LOOP SIEVE
    sieve_inner_loop_condition:
        movl %eax, %ecx                 # %ecx = %eax (i)
        imul %ebx, %ecx                 # %ecx = %eax (i) * %ebx (j)
        cmpl %edx, %ecx                 # compare %ecx (i*j) with N
        jb sieve_inner_loop_statements  # if i*j < N, enter loop-statements
        incl %eax                       # if not, increment %eax (i)
        jmp sieve_outer_loop_condition  # check outer-loop condition again, loop

    sieve_inner_loop_statements:
        movl %ecx, %esi                 # %esi = %ecx (i*j)     
        movl $0, (%edi, %esi, 4)        # arr[i*j] = 0, allocating 4 bytes for integer value 0
        incl %ebx                       # increment %ebx (j)
        jmp sieve_inner_loop_condition  # check innver-loop condition again, loop

    exit:
        movl %edi, %eax                 # return array

    # Epilogue, clean up the stack
    popl %ecx
    popl %ebx
    popl %edx

    popl %edi
    popl %esi
    movl %ebp, %esp
    popl %ebp
    ret
```

Comment: In the C version `N` is a function argument. You asm version doesn't even get it, how should it have the correct value? Change your asm function to take same two parameters as the C version.

Comment: @Jester What? Every variables initialized in C here is placed directly on top of the stack, which I am assigning to the working registers in the asm function.

Comment: You don't get access to variables of the caller. Especially not with negative offset from `ebp` since those are your own locals (or would be, if you allocated any). asm isn't any different from C, at least when invoked according to the C calling convention. Use the same logic.

Comment: Aaah I see. Gonna try this later to see if that was causing the wrong output

Comment: Posting code as a picture invites down votes.  Posting code as text is more useful.

Comment: @Jester I tried what you said, but I still get the same output in the array. Any suggestions? I've updated the post with my current C code. I also get a segfault in the assembly code, which seems to be the way I am returning the array to C, but I think the way I am doing it is completely valid? I mean, %eax should hold the address of the array. If not, my offset on the stack might be wrong.... or?

Comment: `arr` is at `+8(%ebp)` and N is at `+12(%ebp)` then. Update your constants.

Comment: Ok I've done this now, but the output is wrong. I'll update the post with the output

Comment: Edited once more now... feeling quite frustrated now as I really cannot understand why I get the wrong output at this moment

Comment: `leal arr(%ebp), %edi` should be `movl arr(%ebp), %edi`. As your comment correctly says what you did was `&arr` but that's not what you need. You need `arr`.

Comment: Also, your array is 4 bytes each, you need to scale by 4 in assembly. C does that for you automatically. So you need stuff like `movl $1, (%edi, %esi, 4)`. Make sure you scale the index not the base.

Comment: And you got your `i < N` comparisons reversed and you are printing the results wrong. :)

Comment: @Jester Damn, I thought it was the other way. Thank you for pointing that out. Now im curious how I am going to print the result. Can I not mov the address of **%edi** which holds the array, into **%eax**, and then access and print the elements using a pointer like I have? If not, why?

Comment: My program freezes now upon running it, which is probably caused by whatever I am doing wrong printing the results :)))))

Comment: You should use the exact same code for printing as the C version except replace `arr` with `arr_asm` or `ptr`. The current printing code should not cause a crash but it prints elements offset by 2 because `i` starts from 2 but `ptr` points to `arr_asm[0]`.

Comment: @Jester Thank you so much for all your help on this, it truly gave me a better understanding of assembly. Managed to fix up the code now with some debugging - the main issue was that some of my counters inside the inner loop never reset when the outer counter incremented (derp). I hope others can benefit from this post. I'm updating the post now with the working code (it is not so pretty, but as it is my first take on assembly, I guess it'll do). Thanks again to Jester!